# Filtering column values based on another column condition

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataset with multiple columns out of which 2 columns I want to use to filter data as follows:

1. In the Reason column keep all row values that are A3
2. In the Reason column keep all values (even null) that has a date(obj) in Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)

*feel free to assign a value for the nulls in reason that have date in GID

and drop the other values like c,b..

have used this code which works for A3 values fine:

> Df = Data[Data["Reason"].isna(['A3'])] ....?

> `df=pd.DataFrame({'Reason':{0: 'b',1: 'c',2: 'a3',3: ' ',4: ' ',5: 'a3',6: 'a3',7: ' ',8: 'b',9: ' ',}, 'Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)':{0: ' -1',1: '2 ',2: ' ',3: ' ',4: '2021-11-03T00:00:00',5: '2021-11-03T00:00:00',6: '',7: '',8: '0.5',9: '2021-11-03T00:00:00'}})`

| Reason | Goods_Issue_Date_(GID) |
| --- | --- |
| b | -1 |
| c | 2 |
| a3 |  |
|  | 2021-11-03T00:00:00 |
|  | 2021-11-03T00:00:00 |
| a3 |  |
| a3 |  |
|  | 0 |
| b | 0.5 |
|  | 2021-11-03T00:00:00 |

Comment: Are the values in the right column actually `str` types?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your date formats always end in 00:00

```
df[(df['Reason']=='a3') | (df['Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)'].str[-5:]=='00:00')]

  Reason Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)
2     a3
4           2021-11-03T00:00:00
5     a3    2021-11-03T00:00:00
6     a3
9           2021-11-03T00:00:00
```

Comment: the code worked fine but it also includes rows that are empty in both columns

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df['Reason']=='a3') | pd.to_datetime(df['Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```